# Automating Web form Filling using Selenium, Python with Excel

Tags: python, excel, selenium, browser-automation

I am looping through a column of excel file to auto-complete the form for me and submit. However, the challenge is that:

- I cannot input the value in the excel column into the first field for the form.

[image]

- The div element for the form gives me element not clickable before sending the value.
  See how the form looks here:

Img1:
[image]

Img2:
[image]

The first field(Artist) automatically opens up with values when you manually start to type the name before the option comes for you to select.

My Python script is below:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import pandas as pd
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time

#Read Data file
df = pd.read_excel('try.xlsx')

#Import Driver components
driver = driver = webdriver.Chrome('/home/dev-mike/.wdm/drivers/chromedriver/linux64/88.0.4324.96/chromedriver')
url = 'myurl'
username = 'myname.com'
password = '****'

driver.get(url)
time.sleep(2)
driver.find_element_by_id("email").send_keys(username)
time.sleep(1)
driver.find_element_by_id("password").send_keys(password)
time.sleep(1)
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='app']/main/div/div/div/div/div[2]/form/div[4]/div/button").click()
time.sleep(1)
driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div/div[1]/div[3]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/button").click()

# #Inside Dashboard
for i in df.index:
    entry = df.loc[i]

    #Name Field
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div/div[2]/aside[1]/div/div[2]/div/form/div[1]/div/div/div/div[2]/span').click()
    time.sleep(10)
    artist_input = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div/div[2]/aside[1]/div/div[2]/div/form/div[1]/div/div/div/div[3]/ul/li[1]/span/span')
    artist_input.send_keys(entry['Artist'])
    time.sleep(1)

    title_input = driver.find_element_by_id('input-2')
    title_input.send_keys(entry['Title'])
    time.sleep(1)

    medium_input = driver.find_element_by_id('input-3')
    medium_input.send_keys(entry['Medium'])
    time.sleep(1)
```

A cross-section of my form-field elements looks like this:
This is based on the assumption that is typing Paul in that input field.

```html
<div class="fb-select fb-element">
  <div class="v-popover display-block">
    <div
      aria-describedby="popover_qmz2wjbcfu"
      class="trigger"
      style="display: inline-block"
    >
      <span class="fb-select__label">Artist</span>
      <div tabindex="-1" class="multiselect fb-select__field">
        <div class="multiselect__select"></div>
        <div class="multiselect__tags">
          <div class="multiselect__tags-wrap" style="display: none"></div>
          <!---->
          <div class="multiselect__spinner" style="display: none"></div>
          <input
            name=""
            type="text"
            autocomplete="nope"
            placeholder="Start typing..."
            tabindex="0"
            class="multiselect__input is-focusable"
            style="width: 0px; position: absolute; padding: 0px"
          />
          <!---->
          <span class="multiselect__placeholder"> Start typing... </span>
        </div>
        <div
          tabindex="-1"
          class="multiselect__content-wrapper"
          style="max-height: 300px; display: none"
        >
          <ul class="multiselect__content" style="display: inline-block">
            <!---->
            <li class="multiselect__element">
              <span
                data-select=""
                data-selected=""
                data-deselect=""
                class="multiselect__option"
                ><span>Paul Gauguin</span></span
              >
              <!---->
            </li>
            <li class="multiselect__element">
              <span
                data-select=""
                data-selected=""
                data-deselect=""
                class="multiselect__option"
                ><span>Paul Kaspa</span></span
              >
              <!---->
            </li>
            <li class="multiselect__element">
              <span
                data-select=""
                data-selected=""
                data-deselect=""
                class="multiselect__option multiselect__option--highlight"
                ><span>Paula Rego</span></span
              >
              <!---->
            </li>
            <li style="display: none">
              <span class="multiselect__option"
                >No elements found. Consider changing the search query.</span
              >
            </li>
            <li style="display: none">
              <span class="multiselect__option">Nothing found</span>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!---->
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I am open to make you understand further if this explanation is not clear?

Comment: @NatRiddle could you check it out again. I have added code snippet

Answer (score 0):

use :

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath(f"//div[@role='option'][normalize-space(.)='{your_input_text}']").click()
```

if it doesn't work, please say what site is it and I check what for you.

Comment: didn't work out though. But how can I reach you on.

Comment: you can mail me, here you are m.safarzadeh1999@gmail.com